Tailwind doesn't have heading in react email
I was wondering why <heading> doesn't work inside <Tailwind>

const Email = () => {


    return(
        <Html>
            <Head />
                <Heading as="h1">testin1</Heading>

            <Tailwind>
               

                <Body className="bg-white my-12 mx-auto">
                
                    <Container className="p-8 rounded-lg shadow-lg">


                        <Heading as="h2">tesgin2</Heading>
                       
                        <Text>{message}</Text>

                       
                    </Container>
                </Body>
            </Tailwind>
        </Html>
    )
}





export default Email



I have been trying to use different kind of heading but nothing seems to work for me. I would like to have the heading inside of the tailwind if possible
